# How to make target of seam redirect rule open in new window?

Tags: navigation, seam

I have the following navigation rule in a seam project. The page needs to open a new window with this URL.

```
<rule if-outcome="goSmc">
    <redirect url="http://smc.ba.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/smc.cgi?dev=#{thisHost}&amp;rm=all_targets" />
</rule>
```

Is there some way to encode a new window on a URL?  Or a seam navigation rule?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [_target](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/_A_TARGET.html) in the `<a href>` to open the link in a new window

**Update**

Ok, so my guess is it is not possible to do this using the navgation rule in seam. However, I have an idea how you can hack this.
Redirect to a page, where you have an onLoad javascript that opens the url you want in a new window, as described on [this](http://www.codeave.com/javascript/code.asp?u_log=7012) page

Comment: Correct, there is no <a href> tag exactly.  It's a redirect rule and it seems no way to add attributes to the generated <a> tag.